# can't find cacheFactory in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-services

Recently, I attempt to replace angular1 to angular2. But I can't find tutorials about cacheFacotry in angular2. Can anyone provide me with some technical tutorials. Detailed usage of cacheFactory will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `$cacheFacotry` in angular 2. Instead we should manage cache as observable collections such as BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject etc.